# Python Append JSON list within for loop

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

I have the following Python code which takes data from cassandra database.
What i want to achieve is to have json encoded variable at the end.
However, not surprisingly, my code only attaches the latest data row to the variable.

How can I combine or append all of the data to a single variable?

```
for key, columns in crime.get_range():
    data = json.dumps(columns)
```

Thanks

I am using Pycassa as a library to access Cassandra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect all the data in a list first, then encode that list:

```
data = json.dumps([columns for key, columns in crime.get_range()])
```